# Should I be worried about anti-cheating system?

Tags: support, voting

So I'm teaching myself typescript and as a result I have quite a big number of questions about it, like 1-2 a day. One particular member of the community (whom I do not know personally) is particularly knowledgeable in the topic and is willing to assist, so naturally most of these questions are answered by him and accepted by me.

Should I be worried, that the anti-cheating algorithms decide that we are trying to game the system and earn some undeserved rep and apply some repercussions?

Comment: Probably not. Not too uncommon for this to occur in less frequented tags. Worst case scenario a few votes might be undone, but no real harm.

Comment: I also have the same feeling, but regarding the vote system. For example, I've upvoted dozens of Shog9's answers in meta because they are really good and he is very active. Since meta votes does not generate rep, I'm not so afraid of upvoting. But in SO, I follow the [sql] tag and constantly see nice answers from Gordon Linoff but I don't upvote him anymore afraid to be identified as a serial voter.

Comment: We don't know how smart the anti-cheating system is and the details are hidden on purpose to avoid people to abuse from it weaknesses.

Comment: I can assure you that *reputation* doesn't factor into this, @Zanon - the checks that run look at vote patterns, not reputation. The checks are in place to identify *anomalous* voting; you can probably observe that there's nothing anomalous about voting for Gordon's answers.

Comment: I doubt you'd be picked up if you upvote each question as it's answered. AFAIK the serial voting algorithm looks for voting on multiple answers at the same time. Unless you ask a bunch of questions and then upvote all the answers at the same time I doubt it will matter.

Comment: @zespri Maybe this is a coverup for you being that other account...

Comment: I'd be willing to bet too that if you serial up-vote several answers by the same author in a short time period (seconds) it behaves much differently than if you up-voted each new question that was posted by a certain author.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Not unless, y'know, you're actually cheating.

As KevinB mentioned in the comments, it is common for top answerers to receive a disproportionate number of votes in the tags where they're active - both the system and moderators are aware of this. Unless you're coordinating voting in some *unusual* way, you shouldn't have anything to worry about.

As always, vote based on how useful each post's content is and not who wrote it.

Comment: Well *I* know that I'm not cheating, but I do not know if you or the system do. And personally, I've always voted on the merits of the answer. The only time I consider who answered is when I have two equally helpful answers and don't know which to accept, in this case I usually go for lower-rep user because I feel they will benefit from it more.

Comment: "Not unless, y'know, you're actually cheating" - not that the system can actually tell that. If you consistently find someone's posts useful and good, there is definitely a chance you will be accused of cheating. The fact that the answers are valid has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 8):

As from your comment:

> *"The only time I consider who answered is when I have two equally helpful answers and don't know which to accept, in this case I usually go for lower-rep user because I feel they will benefit from it more."*

That's generally OK (I've been applying the same decision myself on a number of questions of mine).

For fairness, you might leave an upvote for equally good answers, and even a comment about your reason of choice.

In general your choice for an accepted answer won't count that much for future research hitting your question and the available answers. Really good answers will be upvoted, no matter if you have decided to choose one of them as accepted.

As a personal anecdote I can give you this sample, where my answer seems to be appreciated much more helpful from the community (researchers), than the currently accepted answer:
[Can Google Mock a method with a smart pointer return type?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11548191/1413395).

Comment: +1, also it's usually worth waiting for around 24 hours before accepting an answer so that you have more answers to choose from.