# Anti-Cheat system & "New Contributor" - looking at his other posts: Serial Downvote?

Tags: discussion, serial-voting, sock-puppets

I read through *[Should I be worried about anti-cheating system?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302773/should-i-be-worried-about-anti-cheating-system)*.

I read/answer mostly Python questions which have a fair influx of new contributors daily. I was happy to see a "New contributor" with over 300 reputation points already - because, tbh: most q/a from new Pythonistas are between abysmal and to_be_improved_upon.

Then I took a look at his other answers... and found several that got accepted, with 2-3 upvotes, but were simply *bad*. Then I looked at the OP ... more "New contributor" - with bad, upvoted OP. There were only two Q/As where A asked, B answer accepted and B asked + A answered accepted - so it is probably not a sock puppet.

I normally would downvote bad answers/questions, but I do not like to get a serial downvoting tab.

Is there a "guideline" of how many downvotes (+comments) I can give one user without being tagged as a serial downvoter?

Comment: The general understanding is: 2 per day, afaik. However, the algorithm is not public, so you can't be sure. It might be more complicated, and account for things like if the question has been asked recently. Do note that what you're doing is very close to the definition of serial voting. You generally shouldn't review questions/answers asked by one specific account and vote on them

Comment: Sometimes that indicates the presence of another sock puppet that is not asking/answering, you could always custom flag and ask the mods to take a look.

Comment: Please do flag this account for moderator consideration, it could still be a sock account or case of ring voting. If you see a pattern of bad content, upvoted, with a few cross-posts like you have here (two users answering each other with higher-than-expected upvotes), we’d like to hear about that.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I'll keep that in mind - for New Contributors I might look at 1-2 other answers and see if they got other "noteworthy" and "upvote" worthy answers to push them above 50. Most of the time they have not, and if I'll only do it for one other contribution. I don't like to be a serial upvoter neither ;o)

Comment: darn .. my "good 300+rep New Contributor" now has 1 rep .. guess something was fishy and he got a outtime, the other one is deleted.

Comment: Hmmmm, funny thing that. Your instincts are good young padawan.

Comment: It's hard to tell these days; an awful lot of awful posts get upvotes. Good eyes, noticing this.

Comment: Also props for not releasing the krak... Meta effect :).

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think that comment belongs in an answer. Sounds like your answer is, "Flag patterns rather than downvote numerous posts."

Comment: @jpmc26: My personal opinion is either the mod speaks up or this should go unanswered.

Comment: @Joshua ? This question isn't about a moderator action. It's about what an ordinary usage should do about a problem they spot. Martijin doesn't need to mention anything about what action has been taken since the question was posted to provide general advice about flagging this sort of thing. I just said that because that comment is a fine answer, and it's better to put answers in answers. I'd have said the same thing if it had been a non-mod posting that comment.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth From what I can tell from my experience it's 3 (per day). I don't know if the votes actually came from the same account, but the small time difference between votes (30 seconds at max) is a strong indicator towards it.

Comment: that robocop helmet suits you fine

Comment: @PatrickArtner for moderator!

Comment: @Patrice in addition to the two moderator answers, just a note that they will not reveal the actual cut off between 'safe voting' and 'user targeting -> revert' as that would allow users to abuse the system and render any related security measures useless.

Comment: @TylerH did you maybe mean to @ the OP of the post here?

Comment: @Patrice Yes, I didn't notice that there was another comment by someone with the same first 6 letters in their username, so I typed the first several and hit tab, not thinking to check afterward.

Comment: @TylerH figured as much, I just wanted to make sure there wasn't a subtlety that I might have missed :)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

> so it is probably not a sock puppet.

Actually, you may well have stumbled upon voting fraud here. Sock accounts need 'bootstrapping', because a sock account can only vote content up if it has at least 15 points. It only takes one accept on an answer posted by a sock account to reach that point.

So if you see a pattern of bad content, upvoted, with a few cross-posts like you have here (two users answering each other with higher-than-expected upvotes), we’d like to hear about that.

Please flag one of the posts you found for moderator attention. Include your findings (name the other account, include all your findings, ask us to investigate if there is voting fraud going on).

> Is there a "guideline" of how many downvotes (+comments) I can give one user without being tagged as a serial downvoter?

The guideline is that you don't go seeking out more content to downvote. Here it was an actual issue that required moderator attention, but in other cases, it is best to trust the wider community to find and downvote bad content, over time.

Answer (score 11):

I've got a pretty simple flow for this that's probably worth reiterating (I've answered quite a few questions similar to this one with the same advice even though the circumstances were different):

- Vote on *content*, not the user.
- If voting on content *leads* to casting more than a few votes in a day toward the same user:

  - Are you up-voting? Great, but vote on other answers, too! When the focus of your votes tends to be centered on a person, benign things tend to look nefarious.
  - Are you down-voting? Flag for moderator attention. If bad content is being incorrectly elevated, or a user has a history of trying to squeak by what should go into a good answer, or if promotional content is being seeded, moderators can deal with this.

So just look for patterns in any direction. If it's a *good* pattern, e.g. you just wish you had more votes to upvote all that great stuff - take care to spread your weight around a little, don't focus on one person.

If it's a *bad* pattern, flag any of their posts as "other" and let the mods know.

Comment: Not entirely sure, but it wouldn't come to my mind to mod-flag someone who is just posting a string of bad answers. Even a string of NAA would probably be a declined mod flag cause the community is supposed to deal with that on its own, no?

Comment: I was looking for upvote-worthy :/ your algo looks sound and what I took from the comments and answers: if in doubt, flag and explain soundly _why_ so moderators can deal with it using my infos on the percieved pattern. I avoid up-/downvoting the same persons more then twice - even though most good/excellent daily answers in python can be attributed to 25-30 ppl - and I regularly stumble over more then two answers / day by them.

Comment: @Magisch While it's rare these days due to automatic blocks and throttling, moderators still do occasionally contact users regarding patterns of not-so-great quality posts that seem to barely skim by the system, and some people have coasted to 10k+ rep on hundreds of such posts. They never _individually_ seem that terrible, but when put together, they don't hold up to a whole lot of scrutiny. It's much more infrequent these days, but it still happens enough to be worth mentioning.